# What are the numbers preceeding a DNS packets flags for?

Tags: domain-name-system, wireshark, packet-capture

What does the `Flags: 0x0500` section of this DNS query packet mean?

```
Domain Name System (query)
    Transaction ID: 0x4242
    Flags: 0x0500 Standard query
        0... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a query
        .000 0... .... .... = Opcode: Standard query (0)
        .... ..0. .... .... = Truncated: Message is not truncated
        .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
        .... .... .0.. .... = Z: reserved (0)
        .... .... ...0 .... = Non-authenticated data: Unacceptable
    Questions: 1
    Answer RRs: 0
    Authority RRs: 0
    Additional RRs: 0
    Queries
        secure.net: type A, class IN
```

This packet seems abnormal as this section would normally be `Flags: 0x0100`.  What is the relevance of this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those flags are described in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) section 4.1.1. THe bit you have set, to get 0x0500 is this

> AA            Authoritative Answer - this bit is valid in responses,
> and specifies that the responding name server is an
> authority for the domain name in question section.

Answer (score 0):

For any reason, Wireshark is not showing the AA (Authoritative Answer) flag, which is enabled in your example.

On my Wireshark that flag is showed:

```
Flags: 0x8180 Standard query response, No error
    1... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a response
    .000 0... .... .... = Opcode: Standard query (0)
    .... .0.. .... .... = Authoritative: Server is not an authority for domain
    .... ..0. .... .... = Truncated: Message is not truncated
    .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
    .... .... 1... .... = Recursion available: Server can do recursive queries
    .... .... .0.. .... = Z: reserved (0)
    .... .... ..0. .... = Answer authenticated: Answer/authority portion was not authenticated by the server
    .... .... ...0 .... = Non-authenticated data: Unacceptable
    .... .... .... 0000 = Reply code: No error (0)
```